# Is there a way to take a .zip file, copy it to a directory on a Windows target and extract the .zip in the directory using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am trying to take a .zip file and copy it to a directory and extract the .zip file afterwards on a Windows target using an Ansible playbook. I was wondering if there's a module or task that can be written to do this nice and clean.

The .zip file itself is stored on another server so the playbook task would be pulling from this location to get the file to copy to the target.

Answer (score 1):

I use these two modules to accomplish that task. `win_copy:` could be used if the file is on your ansible control host.

```
- name: download zlib source
  win_get_url:
    url: "{{ zlib_url }}"
    dest: "{{ boost_workdir }}"
  register: download_zlib
  until: download_zlib is succeeded
  retries: 10
  delay: 2

- name: unzip zlib source
  win_unzip:
    src: "{{ download_zlib.dest }}"
    dest: "{{ boost_prefix }}"
    delete_archive: true
    creates: "{{ boost_prefix }}/zlib-{{ zlib_version }}/contrib"
    copy: false
```

Comment: thank you! For the task to unzip zlib, why did you choose `dest` to be `{{ boost_prefix }}` rather than `{{ boost_workdir }}` like you did up top?

Comment: The boost workdir is a temporary directory where I store the zip, boost prefix is where I unzip the files into.